# Is Ilosovic an actual name?

Tags: names

When I watched live action Disney/Tim Burton Alice in wonderland, I was surprised that one of the characters is named "Ilosovic", because it sounded like a Slavic or eastern European surname despite being the given name for a character who is from Wonderland and not Eastern Europe. But there are sources that appear to say that it isn't an actual name. If it is not how to create sci-fi or fantasy names that don't have names that sound like they could be from another real-world language?

Comment: Hi @ Caitlyn Carvalho, I'm afraid this site is not here to ask about Alice in Wonderland (what we call a 3rd party world), but rather to help you build your own world. We don't answer about whether a name exist in the real world or not, either, as well... Real-world is not a fictional world ^^'. You can get a look at what kind of questions we deal with in the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), [help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [recent, high-voted and open questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+score%3A4)